# Why is the circumference of a circle the derivative of the area of the circle?

Tags: calculus, geometry

$${\frac{d}{dr}}(\pi r^2)=2\pi r$$

Why is that?
And additionaly: Why doesn't hold this for the volume and area of a circle?

Comment: Could you be more specific when you say "Why doesn't hold this for the volume and area of a circle?"

Comment: It does hold: $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dr} \dfrac43 \pi r^3 = 4 \pi r^2$

Comment: As for nice and pretty pictures as to why this holds, see [3blue1brown's calculus videos](https://youtu.be/WUvTyaaNkzM?list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr&t=87) This particular time stamp deals with why$$\int_0^R2\pi r~\mathrm dr=\pi R^2$$but you can apply the reasoning backwards.